# bosun never send unknown notifications

Tags: alert, bosun

Unknown notfication is really struggling me and the official docs seems newer than released bosun binary, like `unknownPost` is ilegal option.

The following unknown template and notification do not work. I can see unknown notfications in bosun UI, but it doesn't send notification(http alert). Other normal alerts work fine.

```
template tmpl_unknown {
    body = 'x'
    subject = `{{$v := .Eval .Alert.Vars.val }}{"warn_undo": [{"app":"xxx","db_type":"NOSQL","db_cat":"aaaa","ip":"{{.Group.host}}","warn_level":1,"warn_type":"cpu","warn_detail":"cpu {{.Group.device}} total util is {{$v.Value | pct}} ","notifier": "xxxxxxxx","status":"undo","report_time":""}]}`

    # body = {{.Name}}: {{.Group | len}} unknown alerts
    # subject = `{"warn_undo": [{"app":"aaaa","db_type":"NOSQL","db_cat":"aaaa","ip":"x.x.x.x","warn_level":1,"warn_type":"alive","warn_detail":"Time: {{.Time}} xName: {{.Name}}  Alerts:{{range .Group}}{{.}},{{end}}","notifier": "xxxxxxxx","status":"undo","report_time":""}]}`

    unknown_alive = `
    {"warn_undo": [{"app":"aaaa","db_type":"NOSQL","db_cat":"aaaa","ip":"x.x.x.x","warn_level":1,"warn_type":"alive","warn_detail":"Time: {{.Time}} Name: {{.Name}}  Alerts:{{range .Group}}{{.}},{{end}}","notifier": "xxxxxxxx","status":"undo","report_time":""}]}`
}

unknownTemplate = tmpl_unknown


notification gcsx_unknown {
        post = ${sys.gcsAlert}
        contentType = application/json
        print = True
        timeout = 5m
        next = gcsx_unknown
        unknownBody = unknown_alive
        bodyTemplate = subject
        # unknownMinGroupSize = 5
        # unknownThreshold = 0
}

alert cpu_total_util_or_unknown {
        template = tmpl_unknown
        $val = avg(q("none:0all-last:cpu.pct_used{host=*,device=total}", "1m", ""))
        warn = $val > 60
        warnNotification = gcsx_unknown
        runEvery = 1
        unknown = 1m
}
```

I want to alert cpu usage. If host is gone, no data reported and I will got an unknown alert.

Bosun version: the newest compiled from master branch(2018.10.08)

Answer (score 0):

After digging the code, I found the issue finally and it's simply:

unknown notification must be sent as `critNotification`

`cmd/bosun/sched/check.go:290`

```
    incident.NeedAck = true
    switch event.Status {
    case models.StCritical, models.StUnknown:
        notify(a.CritNotification)
    case models.StWarning:
        notify(a.WarnNotification)
    }
```

Change `warn`, `warnNotification` to `crit` and `critNotification` and notfication is sent successfully. This should be documented in bosun.org.

`unknownPost` is a legal option, just like `unknownPost`,`unknownGet`,`unknownBody`,`unknownEmailSubject`. But they should be defined in template variables, or it will report error:

```
2018/10/11 16:19:36 fatal: main.go:130: couldn't read rules: conf: bosun_rule.conf:47:0: at <alert x...>: 
notification x uses template key unknown_post in unknown post url, but template cpu_util does not include it
```

The right way is:

```
template tmpl_unknown {
    unknown_alive = `
    {"warn_undo": [{"app":"xxx","db_type":"NOSQL","db_cat":"aaaa","ip":"x.x.x.x","warn_level":1,"warn_type":"alive","warn_detail":"Time: {{.Time}} Name: {{.Name}}  Alerts:{{range .Group}}{{.}},{{end}}","notifier": "xxx","status":"undo","report_time":""}]}`
    unknown_post = "//x.x.x.x:7777/alert"
    # unknown_post = {{ V "$gcsAlert" }}
}

notification gcsx_unknown {
        post = ${sys.gcsAlert}
        contentType = application/json
        print = True
        timeout = 5m
        next = gcsx_unknown
        unknownBody = unknown_alive
        unknownPost = unknown_post
}
```

As you note that the http url prefix `http:` need to be removed.